# Is there any metadata-holding mechanisms in Mathematica programming similar to Java annotations?

Tags: documentation, java, comment

I'm re-implementing some tools previously implemented in Java in Wolfram Language. Is there any metadata-holding mechanisms in Mathematica programming similar to [Java annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html)?

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with Java could you perhaps summarize the key features, differences, or advantages of Java annotations over traditional comments, etc.?

Comment: I don't know if you consider these to be similar, but for smaller projects I'd use messages, e.g. `f::meta = "\n Author: Some One \n Date: 2014.8.14"` and then `Message[f::meta]`, and for bigger project I'd create documentations [see](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/documentationpaclets/index.html)